# How to use one class to extend multiple classes (not multiple inheritance)?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, javascript-inheritance

Here's a couple of JS classes. The `GrandChildOne` and `GrandChildTwo` classes are identical, but extend different parent classes. Since their code is identical I'm looking for ways to get rid of this duplication. In other words, I'd like to have one class (let's call it `GrandChild`) and use it to extend  `ChildOne` and `ChildTwo` classes. Any advice?

```
class Parent {
  someParentMethod () {
     console.log('Parent')
  }
}

class ChildOne extends Parent {
   someChildOneMethod () {
     console.log('someChildOneMethod')
  }
}

class ChildTwo extends Parent {
   someChildTwoMethod () {
     console.log('someChildTwoMethod')
   }
}


// THE CLASSES BELOW ARE IDENTICAL
class GrandChildOne extends ChildOne {
   someGrandChildMethod() {
     console.log('someGrandChildMethod')
   }
}
class GrandChildTwo extends ChildTwo {
   someGrandChildMethod() {
     console.log('someGrandChildMethod')
   }
}

const grandChildOne = new GrandChildOne()
const grandChildTwo = new GrandChildTwo()
```

Comment: "How to use one class to extend multiple classes (not multiple inheritance)" what do you mean by "not multiple inheritance"? Extending multiple classes is multiple inheritance. Which I assume you know is not supported. So I'd say you should either lift this common code up to common base or use some other approach (mixin, composition)

Comment: By ("not multiple inheritance") I meant to say that I'm not looking for something like `class Child extends ParentOne, ParentTow {}` (I was unsure it's not supported). But, yeah, you were right — mixins are a way to go. Thank you, sir!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use Mix-ins for this ([example in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Mix-ins))

It would be something like this:

```js
class Parent {
  someParentMethod () {
     console.log('Parent')
  }
}

class ChildOne extends Parent {
   someChildOneMethod () {
     console.log('someChildOneMethod')
  }
}

class ChildTwo extends Parent {
   someChildTwoMethod () {
     console.log('someChildTwoMethod')
   }
}


// define GrandChild as a Mix-in:
let GrandChild = Base => class extends Base {
  someGrandChildMethod() {
     console.log('someGrandChildMethod')
   }
};

//Then:
class GrandChildOne extends GrandChild(ChildOne) { }
class GrandChildTwo extends GrandChild(ChildTwo) { }

const grandChildOne = new GrandChildOne()
const grandChildTwo = new GrandChildTwo()

grandChildOne.someChildOneMethod();
grandChildTwo.someChildTwoMethod();
```

Comment: That's exactly what I need! You're a legend, sir!